# I want to implement grey foregound with instruciton in my ios App

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, foreground

I want to implement something like this in my ios app :[image]

I want a transparent foreground with a warning message similar to "please enable Bluetooth to continue using this app" in my ios App. How can I implement a similar kind of behavior in my app?

Comment: I am using this library : https://github.com/SwiftKickMobile/SwiftMessages. You can do this with it.

Comment: Thanks, @Picode I don't want any user interaction with the message. I want to display the message when Bluetooth is turned off and dismiss the message once the Bluetooth is turned on.

Comment: did you handle the code to listen to turn on and turn off of bluetooth events?

Comment: Yes @SahilManchanda, I have a callback centralManagerDidUpdateState which is called whenever Bluetooth state changes.

Comment: How do you design your Views? I mean programatically or using storyboard?

Comment: I design my view through storyboard.

Comment: Then design your View in the storyboard and the add it as subview programatically when the bluetooth is turned off and remove it when the bluetooth is turned back on

Comment: Thanks @SahilManchanda I will try it and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var vc: BannerViewController!

    func addBanner(){
        vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "BannerViewController")
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(vc.view)
        let sv = vc.view.superview!
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let constrainst = [
            vc.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.topAnchor),
            vc.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.leadingAnchor),
            vc.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.bottomAnchor),
            vc.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sv.trailingAnchor)
        ]
        vc.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constrainst)
    }

    func removeBanner(){
        vc.view.removeFromSuperview()
        vc = nil
    }
```

The above functions can help you achieve what you want. basically design your banner in storyboard. then have a variable at class level. when the bluetooth is turned off in that callback, call the addBanner function and in the callback function of bluetooth turned on call the removeBanner function.

Comment: the banner view is not covering the navigation bar at the top and though the banner view is showing but it is still allowing the interaction with background view.